# Vaadin Flow in IBM Portal as Portlet

Tags: vaadin, portlet, vaadin-flow

I've been an avid user of Vaadin 8 a couple of years ago for some small projects.
Here in my new firm today, I'd like to bring it in as framework, and I've decided to create a small PoC to show.
We mainly focus on portals and web applications for intranet/portal use: so I'd like to create a small portlet.
Our focus product is IBM Portal and sometimes Liferay

I've googled a bit but all the documentation is for Vaadin 8 of older.

I'd like to make a couple of things:
- create a simple form request portlet in an IBM Portal 8.5+ (so Java8)
- i'd like to pass the page or portlet parameters you can setup in the IBM Portal to the portlet itself to add some customization

Can anybody point me to the right documentation or give me some advice?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The portlet support in Flow is not yet implemented. https://github.com/orgs/vaadin/projects/1 The road map of Vaadin indicates that it could be available in version 14 of the platform, which is scheduled mid 2019. More details can be found here https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4760

Comment: In the meantime, Vaadin 8 is still maintained until 2022, if you know how to use that: https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-framework-8-roadmap-2017-and-beyond